# How to auto cap a textbox

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How do I make it so that when a user types letters into a textbox in silverlight that it changes these letters to all capitals?  And at the same time still fires all the same events such as keypress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no easy way to do it except to use an embedded all caps font.  All other ways interfered with how the textbox worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid code behind or custom controls (preferable), this sort of functionality is available via behaviours.

e.g. this one [in the Expression blend Gallery](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/UpperTextBehavior) converts any text box to which it is  attached into uppercase.

Then is just a matter of drag-drop in Blend or adding the trigger manually in VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be:

```
private void tb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var tb = (TextBox)sender;
  var caret = tb.CaretIndex;
  tb.Text = tb.Text.ToUpper();
  tb.CaretIndex = caret;
}
```

If you wanna save even more performance, handle the LostFocus event instead (which you then don't have to worry about carret position either):

```
private void tb_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var tb = (TextBox)sender;
  tb.Text = tb.Text.ToUpper();
}
```

But if the data is bound to a model/entity I would call the `ToUpper()` on the bound object property setter / `OnPropertyChanged`, `OnTextChanged` or whatever it is in the entity.